# GUI creation(operation on files) using python

Tags: python, user-interface

I am creating a GUI wherein i get an input(filename) from the user.

Then i have to run some shell scripts on that file and display the outputs of each script separately.

I am kinda stuck with the subprocess module. Everytime i run, it throws an error.

And another thing is, how do i create a global string variable, coz i am not able to access a variable i used in one function in another.

CODE:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import subprocess
import os

FileName = ""
FilePath = ""


def browse():

    Tk().withdraw() 
    FilePath = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("ApkFiles","*.apk"),("All files", "*")))
    print FilePath
    Parts = FilePath.split("/")
    FileName = Parts[-1]
    name = str(FileName)
    #print FileName


def process():

    print FileName
    #subprocess.call("cat ", FileName, shell=True)
    #Content = open(self.filename,"r").readlines()
    #print Content
    #subprocess.call("command-name-here")
    #output = subprocess.call(["/path/to/command", "arg1", "-arg2"])
    #subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    #subprocess.call ("ls")

    subprocess.call (['cp filename /Home/dinesh/Base/ApkFiles/'])
    subprocess.call (['cd /Home/dinesh/Base'])l
    subprocess.call (['./AppSplit 0.1 0.1 0.8'])
    Status = subprocess.call (["AppSplit.sh" ,"filename"])
    #exit (Status)
    #   exit (0)



gui = Tk()  #create an object
gui.title("Select an app to be clustered")
gui.geometry("700x400")

GuiLabel1 = Label(gui,text="Select an app to be clustered").grid(row=0 , column=4)
GuiLabel2 = Label(gui,text="ApkFile").grid(row=3 ,column=3)

bar=Entry(gui).grid(row=3, column=4)


button1= Button(gui, text="Browse", command = browse).grid(row=3, column=5)
button2= Button(gui, text="Cluster", command = process).grid(row=4, column=5)

gui.mainloop()  #necessary for windows
```

Comment: What is in your `AppsSplit.sh`? if its possible, just port your shell script to Python. Easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For subProcess.call you need to pass the argument as list of strings for each one not as a single string in the list.

```
subprocess.call (['cp', filename, '/Home/dinesh/Base/ApkFiles/'])
# or use Python
shutil.copy(filename, '/Home/dinesh/Base/ApkFiles/')

subprocess.call (['cd', '/Home/dinesh/Base'])
# or use python
os.chdir('/Home/dinesh/Base')

subprocess.call (['./AppSplit', '0.1 0.1 0.8'])
```

You can put global variable outside the function definition and use they global keyword inside the function

```
globalvar1 = "This is global"

# in the function
def myfunc():
    global globalvar1
```

Comment: global thing worked fine. Now i am able to access the filename globally. But still i am not able to copy the file to the path mentioned above. Below is the error !!!!!!!                                              cp: cannot create regular file `/Home/dinesh/Base/ApkFiles/': No such file or directory
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: The error message indicates that No such file or directory - you need to make sure the directory exists, the copy command will not create directory